# Use value of a data type without pattern matching

Tags: haskell, types, pattern-matching, ghc

Is there any way in Haskell (using ghc), to use a value of a data type directly *without using pattern matching* like in object-oriented programming languages (e.g. obj.a or obj->a) ?

I searching for something like this:

```
data Obj = Obj {a :: Int, b :: Int}

some :: Obj -> Int
some o = o.a
```

Comment: "without using pattern matching like in object-oriented programming languages" – Well, message dispatch is a form of pattern matching, is it not? It is most obvious in Erlang, but it is true of Smalltalk as well.

Answer (score 3):

The closest you can get is Haskell's records, which looks like this:

```
data Obj = Obj {a :: Int, b :: Int}
```

which will automatically give you the functions:

```
a :: Obj -> Int
b :: Obj -> Int
```

which can be called like normal functions (type annotations for clarity):

```
(a (o :: Obj)) :: Int
```

[Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) has a good chapter on them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're already halfway there. By using record syntax, you've automatically created the functions

```
a (Obj x _) = x
b (Obj _ x) = x
```

So you can access the `a` value with `a myObject`.

But yes, as you can see, it does boil down to pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

The `RecordWildCards` language extension is also helpful.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

data Obj = Obj {a :: Int, b :: Int}

some :: Obj -> Int
some Obj{..} = a + b
```